# Write pixel data to certain mipmap level of texture2d

Tags: ios, metal, sample, texture2d, mipmaps

As you might know, `Metal Shading Language` allows few ways to read pixel data from `texture2d` in the kernel function. It can be either simple `read(short2 coord)` or `sample(float2 coord, [different additional parameters])`. But I noticed, that when it comes to writing something into texture, there's only `write` method.

And the problem here is that `sample` method allows to sample from certain mipmap level which is very convenient. Developer just needs to create a sampler with `mipFilter` and use normalized coordinates.

But what if I want to **write** into certain `mipmap` level of the texture? The thing is that `write` method doesn't have `mipmap` parameter the way `sample` method has and I cannot find any alternative for that.

I'm pretty sure there should be a way to choose `mipmap` level for writing data to the texture, because `Metal Performance Shaders` framework has solutions where mipmaps of textures are being populated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The easiest way to do this that I'm aware of is to create a _texture view_ targeting a specific mip level, then writing to that. This is the technique I use for generating pre-convolved cubemaps for image-based lighting.

Comment: Hello @warrenm! Thank you for your response! Do you have any texture view's tutorial/example in mind that worth sharing? I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with *texture views*.

The purpose of texture views is to reinterpret the contents of a base texture by selecting a subset of its levels and slices and potentially reading/writing its pixels in a different (but compatible) pixel format.

The `-newTextureViewWithPixelFormat:textureType:levels:slices:` method on the `MTLTexture` protocol returns a new instance of `id<MTLTexture>` that has the first level specified in the `levels` range as its base mip level. By creating one view per mip level you wish to write to, you can "target" each level in the original texture.

For example, to create a texture view on the second mip level of a 2D texture, you might call the method like this:

```
id<MTLTexture> viewTexture = 
    [baseTexture newTextureViewWithPixelFormat:baseTexture.pixelFormat
                                   textureType:baseTexture.textureType
                                        levels:NSMakeRange(1, 1)
                                        slices:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
```

When binding this new texture as an argument, its mip level `0` will correspond to mip level `1` of its base texture. You can therefore use the ordinary texture `write` function in a shader to write to the selected mip level:

```
myShaderTexture.write(color, coords);
```